# SAKAI Cannot Deploy to TOMCAT

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, sakai, lms

I am trying to setup sakai on my local machine, [these steps](https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai/wiki/Quick-Start-from-Source) when I reached the steps on **Compile Sakai Source Code** I was able to run `mvn clean install` with 'BUILD SUCCESS' output, but when I ran

```
mvn clean install sakai:deploy -Dmaven.tomcat.home=$CATALINA_HOME -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I got the error: [image]
but when I ran the same command above with flag -X then
I got the error: [image]
I have tried what may be the course of the error by going to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException and also tried with the most of the fix suggested there (such as `mvn install` and `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile`. Sincerely speaking I don't know much about maven I just want sakai to work)

I have also searched youtube to see anything different from the installation guide that I followed, there seem to be only 2 videos for sakai and they followed guide closed to what I followed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true sakai:deploy -Dmaven.tomcat.home=/path/to/tomcat`;

Replace `/path/to/tomcat/` with the actual path to tomcat.
This works for me.

Comment: I'd agree, most likely $CATALINA_HOME wasn't defined in the original command so that's why this failed.